# Convert List<Integer> to String

Tags: java, eclipse, string, lambda

I've got a sequence of integers (`List<Integer>`) and want to convert it to a string. I don't see why this code doesn't work:

```
sequence.stream().map(n -> n == 1 ? "+" : (n == -1 ? "-" : Integer.toString(n))).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

As you see, I want `1` to be represented as `+` and `-1` as `-`.

I get the error message `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Stream<Object> to <unknown>`.

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure the error is caused by that line?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? Googling the error message suggests that this is a bug with the Eclipse compiler.

Comment: @binoternary Yeah, I'm using Eclipse. When will this bug be fixed?

Comment: I don't use Eclipse myself so I'm not sure, but this seems to be the relevant bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=480075. It's marked 'fixed' so maybe you just need to update Eclipse.

Comment: My Eclipse(Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600) pretends to be uptodate and has still the bug, as  the fix date is after 20160218.

Comment: Works flawlessly on my older Luna. Apparently, Eclipse’s compiler development is not going forward…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

After reading the comment knowing that Java is alright:

Eclipse isn't aware of `n == 1 ? "+" : (n == -1 ? "-" : Integer.toString(n))).toString()` beeing a String.

```
sequence.stream().map(n -> (String)((n == 1 ? "+" : (n == -1 ? "-" : Integer.toString(n))))).collect(Collectors.joining(","))
```

works fine.

**EDIT**

if you extract it to a function, Eclipse knows its a String:

```
private static String format(Integer n) {
    return n == 1 ? "+" : (n == -1 ? "-" : Integer.toString(n));
}
```

Comment: As soon as I save your line in eclipse (which I have to compile it) eclipse removes `(String)` and comes up again with `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Stream<Object> to <unknown>`. Maybe that's because I'm using AutoFormat on save.

Comment: its the option 'remove unnecessary casts', there are some parts of Eclipse smarter than the others :-)